# Select с массивами PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, java, sql

Помогите с запросом выборки из таблицы, которая содержит поле массив. Необходимо выводить только те строки, в которых в поле-массиве не содержится элемент. Например,  Элемент-"C"

```
<table border=1>
<tr><td>1</td><td>{A}</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>{A,B}</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>{A,B,C}</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>{X,Y,Z}</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>{C,D,E}</td></tr>
</table> <br>
```

Так вот необходимо, чтобы запрос вернул только первую, вторую и четвертую строки. 
Пишу на JAVA.

Comment: я правильно понял в вашей таблице тип поля массив значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where cell not like '%C%'
```

Comment: А не значит ли это что мне не выведет строку и в случаях paCman и WarCraft

Comment: ну так по условиям твоей задачи эти слова подходят, значит все правильно, если таких слов не должно там быть, то или контролируй данные в таблице или уточняй условия выборки

Comment: Пока такой запрос работает, но со временем могут появиться записи AC, BC итп. Хотелось узнать можно ли проверять конкретные элементы массива, а не содержание строки.

Comment: не понял =)

Comment: ну ячейка содержит массив(тип ячейки в постгре). Как я понимаю лайк проверяет не содержимое массива а строку в ячейке.

Comment: мне кажется он проверяет содержимое ячейки, если там массив, он преобразует его в строку, а в ней ищет сходства лайком

Comment: Да так и есть пока за неимением иного буду делать так. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[9.17. Array Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

```
select * from table where not '{C}'::varchar[] <@ cell;
```